# Combine div border with image background

Tags: html, css, image, background, border

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Example]

The width of the element is 100%. I will use only the centered corner and combine with border-top:

```
.element { 
border-top: solid 1px #ccc ; 
background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat center top; 
}
```

But the border stays inside the arrow. I tried `up image background -1px` to hide the border but it didn't work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting issue. Here's one contrived solution using the `:before` selector to absolute position the image over the border. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuaU6/1/) for a working example. The relevant code is as follows:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red; /* For demo purposes it's red */
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3zMs.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: result of above code]

**Edit:** the [browser compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/::before#Browser_compatibility) for the `:before` selector tells us it's only supported in IE8 and higher. It's even worse though, because as far as I can tell the `content: url(...)` construct nor the `background-image` of a :before pseudo-element doesn't seem to work even in IE9. Fortunately, this should fall under graceful degredation...

Comment: I prefer this because I don't have to add another container. The pseudo classes ara awesome!

Comment: Good to hear you like the solution! One thing I should've mentioned though: [browser compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/::before#Browser_compatibility) isn't perfect. In fact, it's even worse than the table implies, it seems IE9 doesn't show the `content: url(...)`. But I guess that's a topic for another question... :'(

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with an extra container:

HTML:

```
<div class="first"><div class="second"></div></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-size: 20%;
    background-position:50% 105%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
    width:100%;
    height:104px;
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROusF7rh7H4mWpr8wQIllxWPAHHIShRyG62xp3qy2O4Av_NmNV) no-repeat;
    background-size: 20%;
    background-position:50% 100%;
}
​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AKpLT/

Answer (score 0):

If you're already creating the image just make the entire thing your background image in the shape you want it. Make it long enough so it can adjust to whatever reasonable length element you might want to put it in.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mash I'd use another element for the background, but unlike Mask I'd use the CSS :before or :after pseudo elements:

```
<h2>Heading</h2>

h2 {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

h2:after {
    background: url(IMAGE);
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: WIDTH-OF-IMAGE;
    height: HEIGHT-OF-IMAGE;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    margin-left: -WIDTH-OF-IMAGE/2;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was going for with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12019853/419956) at first, but margin-left doesn't combine with absolute position, so this will be a few pixels off center.

Comment: Ah I missed your answer, we probably posted at the same time. Anyway, margin-left _does_ work with absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/kuaU6/2/